# Cross-Platform Functional Language for Objective-C

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, cross-platform, ocaml, llvm

**EDIT: After spending several hours researching this, I don't think I'm going to find anything that will actually end up saving me time compared to the amount of time and effort of finding suitable language, suitable bindings, and maintaining that environment in the face of change on all these platforms.  I'm accepting the answer that seems most realistic because it would be the best idea for most people.  The opinion I'm drawing from these conversations and others I'm having is that the only true way forward is to either use a Functional language that can operate without external bindings, or something that has bindings maintained by a commercial entity such as F#.  It's too much work and too little demand and the state of what's available in the wild reflects that.  I hope it changes one day.**

I'd like to start using a functional language in my software, **in addition to** Objective-C which is my primary language (C may be workable as the binding?).  Must be cross-platform, meaning Windows, Linux, OSX (x86), and iOS (ARM).  What should I use and how can I achieve this?

I'm planning to switch to LLVM backend and Clang for my Objective-C soon, if this makes any difference.

I don't have any "knowledge investment" in any functional language, although I've screwed around with a few.  I'm learning one from scratch so I want to learn something non-arcane if possible

- The solution must be **real**, there's a lot of preliminary or prototype work done but..
- I'm using objective C and I really do need Cocoa bindings; because a large amount of my data is using Cocoa types so things would be a mess otherwise.  Also objective-c messaging would prevent me from needing to create glue code between static C functions and my Objective-C object instances (which is already what objective-c method calls are doing built-in..)
- The solution must be license-safe for statically linking (iOS requirement)

Here are examples of what I would like to do:

- Process a language of bytes, for instance a network protocol

  - Input: bytes and length and 'calling' objective-c method instance
  - Output: return to calling objective-c method instance, send it cocoa-container arguments
- Make decisions about the best "move" in a board game

  - Input: cocoa-contained state data, 'calling' objective-c method instance
  - Output: possibly alter state data, possibly call an arbitrary objective-c method, and then return to calling objective-c method instance, send it cocoa-container arguments

Comment: Are you saying you actually use Objective-C to make Windows programs?

Comment: Note that [section 3.3.1](http://daringfireball.net/2010/04/iphone_agreement_bans_flash_compiler) of the developer agreement may give Apple cause to veto your application. I suggest testing the waters before sinking months into development.

Comment: @samold: That article is old. Apple has since relaxed the rules. Look at the section 3.3.1 in the current guidelines and you'll see that it reads differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gambit or Chicken Scheme are probably your best bet — they compile to C.

Comment: @Chuck can these actually mix with C software?  It looks like once they get started they run in their own managed runtime and "take over" .. I can't find any documentation or information for how I can for example create just a library of functions that, when executed, run until completion then return to my code.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Nektarios Did you discover the answer to your question (whether they run in a managed runtime)? Do these actually produce plain C libraries?

Comment: @kizzx2 I gave up completely on functional languages for a multitude of reasons and have unlearned all of these details.  However I do know that before I gave up, Haskell was by far the winner, because it's C FFI showed the most promise of providing what I was asking for

Comment: @Nektarios I know it's off-topic, but I'm extremely curious to why you "gave up completely" on functional languages. Is it because of interop issues like this or other reasons?

Comment: @kizzx2 it's because there was no place for it in anything I was doing, and I don't see the arguments FOR it being valid in a practical sense.  Functional languages are supposedly timesavers; yet they clearly take YEARS to properly learn to the point where they are such. I often saw them used for "heavy lifting", but they are (much) slower and have harder to anticipate performance than imperative languages. Interop wasn't impossible, but in the end I wouldn't use a func lang even if built-in. The only advantage I found of learning a func lang is that it makes you approach problems in a new way

Comment: @kizzx2 I understand my comment won't be popular with the functional language lovers but it's an unbiased opinion of someone who wanted to learn that world and invested a significant amount of time to do so. Yes, I did learn a lot by venturing in, but I also quickly saw it to be a dead end.  Just browsing SO for the problems people encounter sums it up.  Lots of q's from people who have spent a VERY long time learning, still don't understand, and still have very basic issues. From myself, a niche kind of person, func langs are too niche.  Unless you are employed at a financial institution..

Answer (score 6):

As Daniel Bünzli mentions, we have an OCaml iPhone app that's for sale right now in the iPhone app store.  (It's a card game named Cassino, if you want to look for it.)  Apple dropped their language restrictions in September 2010, and we encountered no resistance from them whatsoever (though of course we are a very small player).

I put together some tutorial examples for writing iOS apps in OCaml that you can find at our website:

http://psellos.com/ocaml/example-app-portland.html
http://psellos.com/ocaml/example-app-slide24.html

You don't mention whether you want GUI code to be cross platform.  That's a much
harder problem.  Our code uses thin wrappers to access the native Cocoa Touch libraries, which aren't going to work on Linux or Windows.  They do work (at least a subset) on OS X.  You can see some custom (much simplified) Cocoa Touch wrappers in the tutorial examples.

OCaml certainly works well on all the systems you mention.  It seems like a pretty good choice to me (a somewhat biased OCaml enthusiast).

Comment: Hi Jeffrey and thank you for your ocaml resources and for your reply.  I'm not using any GUI functionality of Cocoa.  My use of Cocoa is that I code in objective-c and I use the data types such as NSArray.  Contrast this to working in C++ and using the STL.  I use Cocotron which allows me to cross-compile an implementation of Cocoa for Linux and Windows.  I've investigated your code and, correct or confirm if I am right, basically it seems to wrap calls to UIKit etc.  It didn't appear that your solution allows passing of Cocoa types to pass freely.  Please confirm or correct

Comment: One nice thing about OCaml is the interface to C (the FFI) which is pretty nice once you get familiar with it.  This allows you to pass primitive values in the C subset of ObjC with minimal trouble between the languages, and to make function calls in both directions.  To interface the OO parts you need a more careful plan.  Our in-house code does this (with restrictions), and the tutorials have a much simplified scheme for it.  Building a generalized system for passing objects and other compound values would be a big project.

Comment: Looking at what you've done more closely, I can seee that interfacing with ObjC period looks like it will become a mess in my situation because my implementations of the cocoa/objc runtime don't use strings for selector values for example but instead use integers.  However I may be able to simply interface using the C FFI.

Answer (score 4):

OCaml is not GPL'd. The compiler itself is distributed under the Q Public License and the standard library is distributed under the LGPL with a *static linking exception*. See here for more details :

http://caml.inria.fr/ocaml/license.en.html

Some have already done apps in OCaml which are available on the app store, you don't need to pay 3000€. Follow these instructions :

http://web.yl.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~tosh/ocaml-on-iphone/index.html

http://psellos.com/ocaml/compile-to-iphone.html

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the licenses, I don't think I need to worry about licenses with basically any solution now.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know what a "Functional Language for Objective-C or C" means, but GHC (Haskell) is BSD licensed, and has a nice C FFI. There has also been a lot of work for GHC on iPhone.

Comment: Unfortunately I've dug in to this a bit, GHC is maybe not supported on ARM, HOC project has been dead a year, another project "direct-cocoa" is supposedly starting soon to solve this issue.. nobody in #haskell knew of anything shipping with this

Answer (score 0):

[Xamarin's](https://xamarin.com/) support for [F#](http://fsharp.org/) is pretty good as of mid 2014.